# Why do I get "unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue'" when using ceebox to display YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that is using [CEEBOX](http://catcubed.com/2008/12/23/ceebox-a-thickboxvideobox-mashup/) to display youtube videos in a popup window.

When the video window pops up I get the following exception in IE9:

> Line: 1
>   Error: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined

If I attempt use the debugger I can see the exception has occurred in a section that looks like this *{Formatting is mine}*:

```
try {
    document.getElementById("")
            .SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML(document.location.href.toString()));
} 
catch (e) {
    document.getElementById("").SetReturnValue("<undefined/>"); 
}
```

The markup for the anchor that triggers the popup is:

```
<a class="thickbox" rel="width:640 height:385" 
  href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx" >
  <span style="background-color: White; position: relative; outline-style: none; ">
    <span class="cliplarge" >
      <img src="http://zzz.zzz.com/xxxx.jpg" 
           style="height: 275px; width: 418px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: -35px; "
           alt="Test" title="" />
    </span>
    <div style="z-index:40;position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;top:-140px;left:140px;">
        <img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/VideoPlay.png") %>" />
    </div>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to the form of the URL:

URLs in the form: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx 
are intended to display on the youtube site directly.

Whereas URLs in the form: http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxx 
causes a full screen player to be used which will show in what-ever frame is there…If you put it in the browser URL it takes over full screen of the browser window.

The second form seems to be a better fit for a pop-up window and doesn't exhibit the exception.